# Iterate over objects which are contained in the intersection of two ranges

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++14, std

Is there something in the standard library which allows me to iterate over objects which are contained in the intersection of two ranges?

In particular, given a function object `action`, I want to obtain a program which is equivalent to

```
/* some container supporting a push_back operation */ intersection;
std::set_intersection(first1, last1, first2, last2,
    std::back_inserter(intersection));
for (auto const& element : intersection)
    action(element);
```

without the need of the insertion into `intersection`. Sure, it's easy to write such a code, for example

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class UnaryFunction>
void for_each_in_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
    InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, UnaryFunction f)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    {
        if (*first1 < *first2)
            ++first1;
        else
        {
            if (!(*first2 < *first1))
                f(*first1++);
            ++first2;
        }
    }
}
```

but I hope that there is already something available in the standard library.

Comment: Do you just want a container of pointers to iterate over?

Comment: Range-v3, Boost.Iterator, Boost.Range, etc all have this functionality, but it's not directly in the stdlib.

Comment: @Muscampester No. Just take a look at the [possible implementation of `std::set_intersection` at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). I want the same code with `*d_first++ = *first1++;` replaced by `action(*first1++);`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Function Output Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) from boost:

```
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {2, 4};
    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),
            boost::make_function_output_iterator([](int i) {
                std::cout << i * i << '\n';
            }));
}
```

Comment: Cool thing! I suggest to use [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html), that always points to latest boost version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nothing in STL that can do what do you want in a way that is better than you codes.

The simpler I can think involves `std::for_each()`, <del>`std::find()`</del> `std::binary_search()` (thanks, Rakete1111) and a lambda function. But I don't think it's a good idea because doesn't use the fact <del>that the containers are ordered</del> the searched values are ordered.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
void action (T const & val)
 { std::cout << "- action over " << val << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> v1 { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
   std::vector<int> v2 { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 };

   std::for_each(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(),
                 [&](int val) {
      if ( std::binary_search(v2.cbegin(), v2.cend(), val) )
         action(val);
    });
 }
```

Comment: You can use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) instead of `std::find`, as it is faster because the containers are sorted.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I didn't considered `std::binary_search()`; thanks; so is really better